# Disc integral problem. My answer is different from Wolfram alphas.

Tags: integration

Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the specified line.

$y = e^x, y = 0, x = -1, x = 1$ rotated by x-axis.

So I don't know how to draw the graph but...this is the integral I get:

$$ \pi \int_{-1}^1 e^{2x} \, dx$$

$$ = \pi \left [ \frac{e^{2x}}{2} \right ]_{-1}^1$$

$$ = \frac{e^2}{2} - \frac{e^{-2}}{2}$$

But wolfram alpha says it is this. What is this even?

[image]

Comment: As usual, WA is right. Did you care to evaluate your answer and lookup $\sinh$ ?

Comment: Your answer is right. Wolfram just gave your answer as a decimal.

Comment: $\sinh$ is they _hyperbolic sine_, defined as $(e^x - e^{-x})/2$, so you and Wolfram agree.

Answer (score 1):

The function $\sinh$ is defined by$$\sinh x = \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$$ so Wolfram Alpha is giving you the answer $\frac{e^2-e^{-2}}{2}$ which is the answer you got.

Note that you dropped the $\pi$ factor on the last line so the answer is actually $\pi \sinh 2$.